# I'd like to get a list of the top posts of all time in a subreddit using praw

Tags: python, reddit

I can get the top posts for a certain day using the code below. Is there any way I can change this to the top posts of all time instead?

```
import praw

user_agent = "Comment Reader 1.0 by /u/crowbell"

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)

submissions = r.get_subreddit('askreddit').get_top(limit=5)
for x in submissions:
    print str(x)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/PRAW-1.0.9/praw.html#praw.objects.Subreddit.get_top_from_all), looks like `get_top_from_all()`

Comment: What does get_top do then? Which time period is used? I cannot find the answer in the documentation.